# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function on index.js

Tags: firebase, react-redux, google-cloud-firestore

Hi i get this error when in my browser when i run my code:

TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
./src/index.js
src/index.js:31

28 |     firebaseStateName: 'firebase'
  29 | }
  30 | const initialState = {};

> 31 | const store = createStore(rootReducer,initialState,
>     32 |     compose(
>     33 |         applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({ getFirebase, getFirestore })),
>     34 |         reactReduxFirebase(firebase, config),

i tryed using thing libary:

http://docs.react-redux-firebase.com/history/v3.0.0/docs/integrations/thunks.html

however still no succes :/

below my index.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import rootReducer from './store/reducers/rootReducer'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { createFirestoreInstance, reduxFirestore, getFirestore } from 'redux-firestore';
import { ReactReduxFirebaseProvider, reactReduxFirebase, getFirebase } from 'react-redux-firebase';
import fbConfig from './config/fbconfig'
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'
import 'firebase/auth'
import 'firebase/storage'
import 'firebase/functions'

firebase.initializeApp(fbConfig);
firebase.firestore();
firebase.storage().ref();
firebase.functions();
const config = {
    useFirestoreForProfile:true,
    userProfile: 'Klanten',
    userFirestoreForProfile: true,
    attachAuthIsReady: true,
    firebaseStateName: 'firebase'
}
const initialState = {};
const store = createStore(rootReducer,initialState,
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({ getFirebase, getFirestore })),
        reactReduxFirebase(firebase, config),
        reduxFirestore(firebase)
    )
)

store.firebaseAuthIsReady.then(() => {
    const rrfProps = {
        firebase,
        config: fbConfig,
        dispatch: store.dispatch,
        createFirestoreInstance
    }

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><ReactReduxFirebaseProvider {...rrfProps}><App /></ReactReduxFirebaseProvider></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
    serviceWorker.unregister();
})
```

this is my rootReducer.js

```
import authReducer from './authReducer'
import shopReducer from './shopReducer'
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { firebaseReducer } from 'react-redux-firebase'
import { firestoreReducer } from 'redux-firestore'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    firebase: firebaseReducer,
    firestore: firestoreReducer,
    auth: authReducer,
    shop: shopReducer
})

export default rootReducer
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is where your problem is:

```
    reactReduxFirebase(firebase, config),
    reduxFirestore(firebase)
```

There has been a little change in the configuration in the latest version, which you must use if you're using react V6.

*Make sure you install the latest version by typing:

```
npm i --save react-redux-firebase@next
```

http://docs.react-redux-firebase.com/history/v3.0.0/docs/v3-migration-guide.html

```
+ import { ReactReduxFirebaseProvider } from 'react-redux-firebase'
+ import { createFirestoreInstance } from 'redux-firestore'
- import { reactReduxFirebase } from 'react-redux-firebase' // removed
- import { reduxFirestore } from 'redux-firestore'          // removed

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  compose(
-    reactReduxFirebase(firebase, rrfConfig), // removed
-    reduxFirestore(firebase)
    //  applyMiddleware(...middleware)       // removed
  )
)

+ const rrfProps = {
+   firebase,
+   config: rrfConfig,
+   dispatch: store.dispatch,
+   createFirestoreInstance // <- needed if using firestore
+ }
const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
+   <ReactReduxFirebaseProvider {...rrfProps}>
      <Todos />
+   </ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
  </Provider>
);
```