# Accessing firebase API using redux in React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux-firebase

I am creating a react app that should connect to Firebase and query Firestore. I am using react-redux-firebase and redux-firestore to connect to the Firebase API. I however get an error indicating that an Object... is not a function. please assist. Below is my code

I import the two like so

```
import { reduxFirestore, getFirestore } from 'redux-firestore';
import { reactReduxFirebase, getFirebase } from 'react-redux-firebase';
```

then I import my Firebase config file like so:

```
import fbConfig from './config/fbConfig';
```

My store then follows:

```
const store = createStore(rootReducer, 
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({ getFirebase, getFirestore })),
      reduxFirestore(fbConfig),
      reactReduxFirebase(fbConfig)
    )
  );
```

The affected line is this

```
applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({ getFirebase, getFirestore })),
```

It says Type error Object is not a Method.

Please assist. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This error is usually related to the version of the `react-redux-firebase` that you are importing. Please, run the below command, to check if this fixes your compatibility issues.

```
npm i --save react-redux-firebase@next
```

Besides that, as indicated in this other post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55559816/typeerror-object-is-not-a-function-on-index-js) and in the official documentation [here](http://docs.react-redux-firebase.com/history/v3.0.0/docs/v3-migration-guide.html), you will need to change your code to fits in the needed setting, for it to work.

Your new code should look more like this.

```
import { ReactReduxFirebaseProvider } from 'react-redux-firebase'
import { createFirestoreInstance } from 'redux-firestore'

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  compose(
  )
)

 const rrfProps = {
   firebase,
   config: rrfConfig,
   dispatch: store.dispatch,
   createFirestoreInstance // <- needed if using firestore
 }
const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
   <ReactReduxFirebaseProvider {...rrfProps}>
      <Todos />
   </ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
  </Provider>
);
```

**This code is untested**, however, it's based in successful cases and the official documentation, so I believe it should help you. I would recommend you to give it a try using it and checking the URLs I linked here, if you want a better understanding of your issue.

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: this worked, thanks. was getting initialization error but I fixed that by passing firebase to reduxFirestore. Thanks

Comment: Hi @David nice to hear it helped you! Please, consider accepting the answer, so this way, the Community can visualize that this solution fixed the issue.